# Defining chapter in LaTeX under amsart

Tags: chapters, amsart

I am writing a file in `LaTeX` and I have a problem: I can't define a chapter in my file under `amsart`.  There is a warning saying "undefined control sequence".

How can can I define a new operator to create chapters, like in books in the preamble?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd,matrix,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing}

\usepackage{
  %amsmath,
  %amsthm,
  amssymb,
  euscript,
  %enumerate,% better enumitem
  url,
  verbatim,
  calc,
}

\textwidth6.5in
\textheight9in
\oddsidemargin.2in
\evensidemargin.2in
\topmargin-1cm
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}%[theorem]
\newtheorem{defn}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{qns}[theorem]{Question}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{ex}[theorem]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}%[section]
\newtheorem{eg}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{obs}[theorem]{Observation}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}%[section]
%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}%[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}%[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}%[section]
\newcommand{\QQ}{\mathbb Q}
\newcommand{\ZZ}{\mathbb Z}
\newcommand{\CC}{\mathbb C}
\newcommand{\FF}{\mathbb F}
\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb R}
\newcommand{\NN}{\mathbb N}
%\operatorname{deg}{{\deg}}
\newcommand\sbullet[1][.5]{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#1}{$\bullet$}}}}}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}
\newcommand{\gen}[1]{\langle#1\rangle}
\newcommand{\Hom}[1]{\text{Hom}_R(#1)}
\newcommand{\lcm}[1]{\text{lcm}(#1)}
%\DeclareMathOperator{\Homm}{\text{Hom}_R( )}
\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{\text{Im}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Ker}{\text{ker}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ch}{\text{char}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\spec}{\text{spec}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\mspec}{\text{maxspec}}
\title[]{Algebra}
\author[]{Ripan Das}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage 
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\chapter{Prerequisites \& preliminaries}
\section{Relation}
\subsection{Introduction}
```

...
[image: I attach the screenshot of my output here]

Edit: As someone suggested, I changed `amsart` to `amsbook`, but now my content looks like this [image]
but I want my content to look like the previous photo

Comment: Maybe try `amsbook`?

Comment: I tried the article preamble and ams book as well but there is a problem my newly defined operators are not working on it and I might need to write the entire code again and it is quite not an easy job

Comment: The main difference between book and article is that articles don't have chapters.  If you change from `amsart` to `amsbook`, the only change you'll notice is that `\chapter` will now be defined.  (And if you're using an AMS class, you automatically get the AMS packages, so you don't need to `\use` them.)

Comment: `amsart` is to produce articles, so does not have Chapters, only Sections and others. Use `book` class, for example.

Comment: "A problem with newly defined operators" can be a new question that we can help you with.  Debugging TeX can be difficult.  I would recommend that you get into the habit of eliminating errors as soon as they happen, and not ignoring them while you continue writing.

Comment: no actually i reduce the number of my errors after writing the code again and again but i want to know how to use AMS class

Comment: as has been said, if you want to use `\chapter` you need a class that defines  `\chapter` such as `amsbook`.   Ignore the _number_ of errors. If you choose  to scroll past the first error then tex can not really recover and may generate dozens of spurious errors. Only ever consider the first error.

Comment: if you want to use amsart just use `\section` as the highest level section, not `\chapter`

Comment: to get a deeper table of contents in amsbook use `\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}` (it defaults to 1)

Comment: The best way to learn how to use a class or package is to read the manual. AMS has two: https://mirror.mwt.me/ctan/macros/latex/required/amscls/doc/amsclass.pdf and https://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/CTAN/info/amscls-doc/Author_Handbook_Mono.pdf.

Comment: Take a look at `\specialsection`.